# How to sleep chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

What I want to do is to pull the proxy from the proxy list and use the other proxy after a certain time after going to the site, but after a certain time how can I use the other proxy, I connect to the proxies in the list very quickly, go to the site and stop the code.

```
var plist = ["154.236.176.30:8081","88.214.41.251:3128"]

getPlist()
function getPlist(){
  for(var i = 0; i < plist.length; i++){
    const myArray = plist[i].split(":");
    var proxy = myArray[0];
    var port = myArray[1];
    setProxy(proxy,port)
    
  }
}
function setProxy(proxy,port){
  
  var config = {
    mode: "fixed_servers",
    rules: {
        singleProxy: {
            scheme: "http",
            host: proxy,
            port: parseInt(port)
        },
        bypassList: ["fp.com"]
    }
  };

  chrome.proxy.settings.set({
    value: config,
    scope: 'regular'
  }, reload(proxy,port));

}
function notifyProxy(proxy,port) {
  chrome.notifications.create(
    proxy,
      {
        type: "basic",
        iconUrl: "icon128.png",
        title: port,
        message: proxy,
      },
      function () {}
    );
    
}
function reload(proxy,port){
    chrome.tabs.reload();
    notifyProxy(proxy,port)
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        var tab = tabs[0];
        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: 'http://www.google.com'});
    });
}
```

Comment: Please use [chrome.alarms](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/alarms/)

Answer (score 0):

To rotate through the proxy list and switch to the next proxy after a certain time, you can use JavaScript's setTimeout function to delay the switching process.

```
var plist = ["154.236.176.30:8081", "88.214.41.251:3128"];
var currentIndex = 0;

// Start the proxy rotation process
rotateProxy();

function rotateProxy() {
  const proxyInfo = plist[currentIndex].split(":");
  const proxy = proxyInfo[0];
  const port = proxyInfo[1];

  setProxy(proxy, port);

  currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % plist.length; // Increment the index and wrap around to the start if necessary

  setTimeout(rotateProxy, 5000); // Switch to the next proxy after 5 seconds
}

function setProxy(proxy, port) {
  var config = {
    mode: "fixed_servers",
    rules: {
      singleProxy: {
        scheme: "http",
        host: proxy,
        port: parseInt(port),
      },
      bypassList: ["fp.com"],
    },
  };

  chrome.proxy.settings.set(
    {
      value: config,
      scope: "regular",
    },
    reload(proxy, port)
  );
}

function notifyProxy(proxy, port) {
  chrome.notifications.create(
    proxy,
    {
      type: "basic",
      iconUrl: "icon128.png",
      title: port,
      message: proxy,
    },
    function () {}
  );
}

function reload(proxy, port) {
  chrome.tabs.reload();
  notifyProxy(proxy, port);
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    var tab = tabs[0];
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { url: "http://www.google.com" });
  });
}
```

Comment: chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: `
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-title.style-scope.ytd-c4-tabbed-header-renderer');
  if (buttons.length >= 2) {
    buttons[1].click();
  }
  const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
  await delay(5000);
  
  const linkButtons = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="watch?v="]');
      if (linkButtons.length > 0) {
        linkButtons[0].click();
      }
  `});
Can you integrate these codes into the codes you posted?

Answer (score 0):

let me know if is this what you were looking for:

```
var plist = ["154.236.176.30:8081", "88.214.41.251:3128"];
var currentIndex = 0;

// Start the proxy rotation process
rotateProxy();

function rotateProxy() {
  const proxyInfo = plist[currentIndex].split(":");
  const proxy = proxyInfo[0];
  const port = proxyInfo[1];

  setProxy(proxy, port);

  currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % plist.length; // Increment the index and wrap around to the start if necessary

  setTimeout(rotateProxy, 5000); // Switch to the next proxy after 5 seconds
}

function setProxy(proxy, port) {
  var config = {
    mode: "fixed_servers",
    rules: {
      singleProxy: {
        scheme: "http",
        host: proxy,
        port: parseInt(port),
      },
      bypassList: ["fp.com"],
    },
  };

  chrome.proxy.settings.set(
    {
      value: config,
      scope: "regular",
    },
    function () {
      reload(proxy, port);
    }
  );
}

function notifyProxy(proxy, port) {
  chrome.notifications.create(
    proxy,
    {
      type: "basic",
      iconUrl: "icon128.png",
      title: port,
      message: proxy,
    },
    function () {}
  );
}

function reload(proxy, port) {
  chrome.tabs.reload();
  notifyProxy(proxy, port);
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    var tab = tabs[0];
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { url: "http://www.google.com" });
  });
}

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-title.style-scope.ytd-c4-tabbed-header-renderer');
if (buttons.length >= 2) {
  buttons[1].click();
}

const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
await delay(5000);

const linkButtons = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="watch?v="]');
if (linkButtons.length > 0) {
  linkButtons[0].click();
}
```

Comment: it didn't work but i fixed it yesterday

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**